# How To use Azure Update management for Automating patch management of all Virtual machines under a subscription including future machines

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-automation, azure-policy, azure-runbook

1. I have an Azure policy which install Microsoft monitoring agent on all the VMs
2. I have Automation Account which is linked to the Log analytics workspace.
3. The Automation Account has a scheduler which has a dynamic query to fetch all the VMs with Tag "PatchManagement" Enabled = $true.
4. The scheduler makes use of the Microsoft Runbook "Patch-MicrosoftOMSComputers" to apply the patched on the Dynamic VMs fetched by the above query.

The Issue is

1. The update management is not Enabled on the Automation Account and the VM's
2. Is there a way we can automate enabling of the Update management on all the VM's created in a subscription and link into the automation account update management using the query of the scheduler.

I followed the link "[enter link description here](https://4bes.nl/2020/07/12/automate-azure-update-management-scheduling-with-powershell/)", to implement this solution.

Comment: Have you gone through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/enable-from-vm) to add VM to update management through Portal

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru-MT, she wants to automate the process not do it manually

Answer (score 1):

The oms agent installation needs a log analytics workspace id parameter which configures the right automation account and log analytics workspace for the VM.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-windows#install-agent-using-command-line

Comment: --> 
I'm able to check the "Microsoft Monitoring Agent has successfully connect" on the VM.

Comment: --> 
I'm able to check the "Microsoft Monitoring Agent has successfully connected" on the VM.
On the Automation Account --> Update Management -->  "Enable" button needs to be clicked manually, would like to know if it can be enabled using script.

https://postimg.cc/f32G20sQ

Comment: https://postimg.cc/svxwm0Xx

Comment: @AnjaliLoganathan, is this something which should be one time for all VMs on automation account/update management section? Or this should be done for each VM?

Answer (score 0):

The link below enables the update management on the automation account.

I was missing the below section of code in my terraform

```
# Enable Update Management solution

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "update_solution" {
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_log_analytics_linked_service.autoacc_linked_log_workspace
  ]
  solution_name         = "Updates"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace.id
  workspace_name        = 
  azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.log_analytics_workspace.name

  plan {

    publisher = "Microsoft"

    product   = "OMSGallery/Updates"

  }

}
```

[Reference link](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/azure-automation-account-update-managent-provider-through-terraform/5947/2)